# Android Connect Physical Device as ADB Device, not Portable Device

Tags: android, windows, android-debug, device-manager

I have a **Nexus 7 Tablet** I want to use for debugging an **Android app** I'm developing.
I'm doing the development and testing on a remote server using **RDP** and sharing my ports, including the **USB** that the tablet is connected to.
Per the instructions in [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Android_Applications_on_a_Physical_Android_Device_with_ADB) article, I have **USB** debugging enabled, and it is operating over the Camera (PTP) protocol.

So everything seems well set up from that side, but despite all efforts, I cannot get **Windows** (on the remote server) to recognize this as anything but a Portable Device.
For debugging purposes, it needs to be registered as an **ADB Composite Device**.
The aforementioned article says that, to overcome this, I need to update the driver software.
I have the **Google USB drivers installed**, but when I attempt to use the Device Manager to update the driver software to the Google USB driver, Windows simply tells me "The best driver software for your device is already installed. Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date. Digital Still Camera."
I've also tried editing the `android_winusb.inf` file with a listing of the tablet's hardware ID as a Composite Android Device, but to no avail.

- How can I tell Windows that I'm using an Android device, not a Portable Device?
- How can I tell it to use the proper drivers when it continues to override me?

Comment: Consumer protocols like MTP typically co-exist with ADB on modern Android devices, so just having the former active does not mean ADB will not be.  Realistically speaking, you are wasting your time trying to do Android development on windows - it is by far the least suited of the three nominally supported platforms.

Comment: @DaniSpringer - please don't make trivial edits to old questions - it merely bumps them in the display for no legitimate purpose.

Comment: @ChrisStratton may I ask if that is your opinion, or if it was discussed on Meta? I strongly believe I should not receive such a comment. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are wrong - all you have done is contributed noise to the site.